# Tkinter background with overlapping buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a scoreboard and i want to add a background to it. If i dont use the background image, my buttons will display but when im using the background image my buttons are 'disappearing'. This is a little piece of my code, how can i place the button in front of the background?. Thanks for helping me.

```
from tkinter import *


player1health = 100
player2health = 100
player3health = 100
player4health = 100


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Scoreboard")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1)

        # Background
        image1 = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Ahmet/OneDrive/Desktop/SC/achtergrond1.png")
        w = image1.width()
        h = image1.height()
        root.geometry("600x500")
        panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
        panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel1.image = image1

        #Player1
        self.Name1 = Label(root, text = input("Name player 1: "), font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.Name1.place(x=80,y=50)

        #scoretracker
        self.Score1 = Label(root,text= 'Score:' )
        self.Score1.place(x=55, y=80)

        self.L1 = Label(root,text= player1health )
        self.L1.place(x=100, y=80)

        self.HP1 = Label(root,text= 'HP' )
        self.HP1.place(x=125, y=80)

        self.add = Label(root, text = "Add",font=("Helvetica", 13))
        self.add.place(x = 30,y=120)
        #button
        player_1_add_10_Button = Button(self, text = "10 HP",)
        player_1_add_10_Button.place(x=30,y=140)

        player_1_add_20_Button = Button(self, text = "20 HP",)
        player_1_add_20_Button.place(x=30,y=170)

        player_1_add_30_Button = Button(self, text = "30 HP",)
        player_1_add_30_Button.place(x=30,y=200)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.configure(background="light blue")
Label(root, text='Scoreboard:', bg= 'light blue').pack()

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Off-topic: You need to use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` from the `PIL` module in order to be able to use a `.png` format file as an image in `tkinter`. You may also need to resize it before use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label containing the background image is a slave of `root`. So are the labels you create in the `init_window()` function, but the buttons are slaves to `self`.

So, instead of:

```
panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
```

try

```
panel1 = Label(self, image=image1)
```

And do the same change for all the buttons as well. That should work better.